# Last column in a TableLayout window not appearing

Tags: java

I want to make a Jeopardy-like game, and to achieve this I decided to use a TableLayout layout. This is what my code looks like now:

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import layout.TableLayout;

public class JeopardyOrtho {
    static JFrame j = new JFrame();
    static JButton [][] buttons = new JButton [5][5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int score = 0;
        for (int r=0; r<5; r++)
        {
            score = score+10;
            for (int c=0; c<5; c++)
            {
                buttons [c][r] = new JButton (""+score);
            }
        }
        j.setResizable(false);
        j.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         double size[][] = {{0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0,20}, // Columns
                    {0.10, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.10}}; // Rows
        j.getContentPane().setLayout(new TableLayout(size));
        for (int r=0; r<5; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<5; c++)
            {
                j.add(buttons [c][r], "" + c + ", " + (r+1));
            }
        }
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Classrooms");
        j.add(label1,"0, 0");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("This thing");
        j.add(label2,"0, 1");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel ("That thing");
        j.add(label3,"0, 2");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel ("Other thing");
        j.add(label4,"0, 3");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel ("Yeah");
        j.add(label5,"0, 4");
        j.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

As far as I can see, running this code should create a 5-column 7-row table, the first row having the placeholder names for the header of each category, the last row being completely blank, and the middle portion filled with a 5x5 grid ala Jeopardy. However, when it is actually run, it looks like this:

[image]

It looks how it should, save for the fact that the entirety of the last column is not showing. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I am assuming that since the program is not throwing an error when I try to put something manually inside those empty cells, those cells do exist, they just won't be filled for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo in the last column.

```
double size[][] = {{0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0,20}, // Columns
                {0.10, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.10}}; // Rows
```

Should be

```
double size[][] = {{0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20}, // Columns
                {0.10, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.10}}; // Rows
```

Also, in the excerpt that you pasted, labels are ill positioned too.
They should be added in row 0

```
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Classrooms");
    j.add(label1,"0, 0");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("This thing");
    j.add(label2,"1, 0");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel ("That thing");
    j.add(label3,"2, 0");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel ("Other thing");
    j.add(label4,"3, 0");
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel ("Yeah");
    j.add(label5,"4, 0");
```

Comment: Oh. Oh my god, I feel so stupid. The excerpt was hastily modified, initially the labels were added as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of a column-row.